# how to get first three characters of an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I return the first three characters of an NSString?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

```
 mystr=[mystr substringToIndex:3];
```

**Be sure your string has atleast 3 ch.. o.e. it will crash the app.**

Here are some other links to check NSsting operations...

[Link1](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C)

[Link2](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsstring.html)

[Apple Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: note: "Range or index out of bounds" error possible if you don't check the length to make sure it has 3 or more characters long

Comment: I'm very new and I searched for this question to try to answer my own, but won't this answer take out the first 3 characters? I use that same syntax to REMOVE the number of characters you set. I'm probably wrong, but thought I should at least ask.

Comment: @RyanBavetta What if the string you are doing this with is for example a date string which your code made earlier on and so you know EXACTLY how many characters it has. Then surely you don't need to bother with an if statement to check how long it is, right??

Comment: @GameLoading I have added some code to your answer so that it doesn't crash for beginners. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Just use mystr = [mystr substringToIndex:MIN(mystr.length, 3)] to avoid crashes :-)

Answer (score 63):

First, you have to make sure that the string contains at least 3 characters:

```
NSString *fullString = /* obtain from somewhere */;
NSString *prefix = nil;

if ([fullString length] >= 3)
    prefix = [fullString substringToIndex:3];
else
    prefix = fullString;
```

`substringToIndex:` will throw an exception if the index you provide is beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Or, wrap in a @try/@catch block. Nonetheless, this is a better answer than the other.

Answer (score 2):

the right way is:

```
text = [text substringToIndex:NSMaxRange([text rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:2])];
```

substringToIndex of NSString is indexing by code unit, emoji takes two code units.

make sure check the index yourself.