# substringFromIndex getting the opposite result

Tags: ios, nsstring

This is my string:

```
NStrring x=@"D1 - Damages";
```

and when  i issue the `[x substringFromIndex:2]`
i got  **- Damages** as the result instead of getting the D1

I just need to get the D1 as the returned string but the above statement is removing the D1 and returning the rest of the character.

Comment: You're using that method wrong. "2" is not a range, it's an integer -- a range has both a location and a length. Go read the docs.

Comment: so this link is not correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294607/how-to-get-first-three-characters-of-an-nsstring

Comment: In that link, they were using substringToIndex, not substringWithRange.

Comment: Sorry Rdelmar yes im using also the substringFromIndex and i am getting that result. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **`substringToIndex:2`** to get `D1`. You are using `substringFromIndex` which is basically saying get the string starting FROM index 2 which will give you `- Damages`