# Get first two characters of NSString

Tags: ios

I have a string an I am trying to get the first 2 characters and the rest of the string. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
NSString *textAll = [arrayOfMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *textMessage = [textAll substringFromIndex:2];
NSString *textType = [textAll substringToIndex:1];
```

the textAll has this form: HEthe message itself.....

textType should return 'HE'
textMessage should return 'the message itself.....'
Textmessage now gives me the message but I can't seem to be able to get the textType...

Comment: @Alessandro *I can't seem to be able to get the textType* is not very useful. What's the expected result and what's the actual one? I suspect you get `H` instead of `HE`, in which case you should look at Martin's answer

Comment: Since you are just getting `H` for `textType` instead of `HE`, it would seem logical to consider changing the `1` to a `2`, right? I would think that would be something worth trying long before posting a question on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get first three characters of an NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294607/how-to-get-first-three-characters-of-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get the first two characters of a string, you want:

```
NSString *textType = [textAll substringToIndex:2];  // <-- 2, not 1
```

From the documentation:

> `substringToIndex:`
>
> Returns a new string containing the characters of
>   the receiver up to, **but not including**, the one at a given index.

(Note that the method expects that the string is at least 2 characters long,
otherwise it throws an exception.)